# javascript error : periodLookup[periodStr] is undefined, why is it throwing this error?

Tags: javascript, html

i have this method:

```
set_period_help_text: function(periodInput){
        var metric = MonitorMetric.getSelectedMetric();
        var periodStr = $('select[name=metric_period]').val();
        var datapoints = Number(periodInput.attr("value"));
        var period = datapoints * periodLookup[periodStr][0];
}

var periodLookup = {
    "OneMinute": [1, "minute"],
    "FiveMinute": [5, "minute"],
    "OneHour": [1, "hour"],
    "OneDay": [1, "day"],
    "OneWeek": [1, "week"]
};
```

where var periodStr is being retrived from a dropdown menue that only has the values:

```
    "OneMinute"
    "FiveMinute" 
    "OneHour"
    "OneDay"
    "OneWeek"
```

i get a java script error when the page loads:

> periodLookup[periodStr] is undefined
>   [Break on this error] var period =
>   datapoints *
>   periodLookup[periodStr][0];

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what is `periodStr`'s value? when it throws?  i bet it doesn't contain what you think.  possible reasons are multiple, like you're running the code before the DOM is ready.

Comment: i think it was the fact it was running code while the value it was trying to retrieve was still not loaded.